# Does str.split() in Python guarantee the order of the returned list

Tags: python

I want to split a string based on a `sep` where the original position of the tokens is important.

In [the official documentation of `str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), nothing is mentioned about maintaining the order of the tokens as they appeared in original text before splitting. Is it guaranteed that `str.split` keeps this order?

Having a text like: `A > B > C`, how can I get a guaranteed output like: `[(1, A), (2, B), (3, C)]`?

Comment: why don't you just test it in the python shell?

Comment: you wont. split does not make tuples, and enumarion starts at 0, not 1.

Comment: For sure I have tested this, but my question is about whether it is guaranteed to always have this output or not, having nothing documented about it. I don't see where is the problem with this question!

Comment: I'm disappointed at the answers and unhelpful comments to this question; examples and simple tests do indicate that the order will be maintained, but the OP is asking if there is a guarantee.  
This is an important question as it may prevent the functionality from being used in some scenarios (such as my current one, so I ended up here trying to find an answer to the same question).  
I will use it for now because it's not so critical if the process that I'm making breaks and all tests do seem to indicate this works as logically expected.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> s = "A>B>C"
>>> lst = s.split(">")
>>> result = zip(range(1, len(lst)+1), lst)
>>> print result
[(1, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (3, 'C')]
```

Comment: Input of `A > B > C` would lead to spaces inside the output.

Comment: Thank you for this hint, the question is about the order guarantee though. Your solution will help achieving the desired output relying on the order of the split.

Comment: For others reading this answer, it will work for Python 2.x. For Python 3.x, the print should look like `print(list(result))` as `zip` returns an `iterator` and not a `list`: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip

Answer (score 1):

This would lead to your output - split alone does not.

```
k = [(n+1,c) for n,c in enumerate( x.strip() for x in "A > B > C".split(">"))]
print(k)
```

Output:

```
[(1, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (3, 'C')]
```

If you do not trust split ... make it explicit:

```
t = "A > B > C"
temp = ""
result = []
for c in t:
    if c == ">":
        result.append(temp.rstrip())
        temp=""
    else:
        temp += c

if temp.rstrip():
    result.append(temp.rstrip())

r = [ (n+1,v) for n,v in enumerate(result)]
print(r)
```

Iterating should be guarateed to be in order - would not make much sense else....

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't have trust problems ;)
I just need a confirmation, should I trust it?